# Error by writing data in a file

Tags: file-io, netlogo

I would like to write data in a file .txt. The problem is that I obtain the error message below by using the following code :

```
No file has been opened.
error while wolf 1 running FILE-PRINT
```

### Code

```
to setup ## Initialization
let new-file-1 "E:/IBM/IBM_outputs/File1.txt"
file-open new-file-1 
write-locations-to-file 
end 

to go 
while [ not time:is-equal (current-date) (end-date) ] [ 
ask wolves [ .... ]
set current-date time:plus current-date 5.0 "minutes" 
write-locations-to-file ] 
end 

to write-locations-to-file
let hour time:show current-date "HH" 
let minute time:show current-date "mm" 
let hourMinute read-from-string hour + ( (read-from-string minute) / 60 ) 

if hourMinute mod 1 = 0 [ 
ask wolves [  
file-print (word who " ; " display-current-date " ; " xcor " ; " ycor " ; " color " ; " [pcolor] of patch-here "\r\n" ) 
] ]
end
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: How about if you just do `file-open "E:/IBM/IBM_outputs/File1.txt" file-print 0`? Does that fail? Surely most of this code is irrelevant to whatever the issue is.